# How to update the contentSize of UIScrollView in a parent controller from a UITableView in Child viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I used the following code to update constraints of parent controller from a child viewController, but it is creating problems:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("in will display row - \(indexPath.row)")
    if (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController is UserPrfileControl){
        if (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).childControllerToUpdate == "userPost"{
            (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).commentViewHeight.constant = 0
            (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).burnedPostsHeight.constant = 0 . 
            (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl).userProfileViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make this code in viewDidLayoutSubviews and please don't use this way (UIApplication.visibleNavigationController.visibleViewController as! UserPrfileControl), just add property for your parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have to try the `self.tableView.reloadData ()`, and then obtain the **tableView contentSize**.